# Creating a view that combines a table and a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a view that combines a table and another view.

The table contains these fields:

- job_no
- ap_tax_exempt

The view contains these fields:

- job_no
- hard_tax_exempt
- soft_tax_exempt

The tricky part is that the job_no values in the view are a subset of the job_no values in the table, and when I combine these to create the new view, I need to make sure they remain unique. In other words, if the table has [1,2,3,4,5] and the view has [2,3,5] the final view should have [1,2,3,4,5] and not [1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5].

Furthermore, not all job_no values in the table have corresponding values for the hard_tax_exempt and soft_tax_exempt columns, so I'm not sure if I need to do something special about that or if SQL is smart enough to automatically assign NULL to those cells.

Example table data:

```
job_no    ap_tax_exempt
------    -------------
  1            True
  2            True
  3            False
  4            False
  5            True
```

Example view data:

```
job_no    hard_tax_exempt    soft_tax_exempt
------    ---------------    ---------------
  2           taxable            NULL
  3          nontaxable          NULL
  4            NULL             taxable
```

I need the final view to be this:

```
job_no    ap_tax_exempt    hard_tax_exempt    soft_tax_exempt
------    -------------    ---------------    ---------------
  1           True              NULL               NULL
  2           True             taxable             NULL
  3           False           nontaxable           NULL
  4           False             NULL              taxable
  5           True              NULL               NULL
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear. You need help to create the SQL, The fact one of the source is a view shouldn't be relevant to the question because you know create view already?

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE VIEW vw_NewView
AS
SELECT COALESCE(t.job_no, v.job_no) AS job_no
       ,t.ap_tax_exempt
       ,v.hard_tax_exempt
       ,v.soft_tax_exempt
FROM TableName t 
FULL JOIN ViewName v
ON t.job_no = v.job_no;
```

See a [Working Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/830d4/2)

Comment: @Rahul for given sample data full join and left join both will give the same result.  If you read the question I think OP is after a full join query.

Comment: that's correct. Added a fiddle demo to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need `left join` because not all `table` record have view. Here is a [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/830d4/4) that proves that it works.

```
CREATE VIEW finalView
AS
    SELECT T.job_no, 
           T.ap_tax_exempt,
           V.hard_tax_exempt,
           V.soft_tax_exempt
    FROM Table T
    LEFT JOIN View V
      ON T.job_no  = V.job_no
```

Comment: I tried this but the resulting view contains only the job_no values in the view, not the ones in the table. So, going back to my example above, the column has 1,2,3 and not 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: Also if you got this result `[1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5].` was because you did a `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: As I mention in my comment the fact one is a view and one is a table doesn't make any difference. Do you want a [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f07e/2)?

Comment: Added a fiddle demo for your answer.

Comment: The result I got was [1,2,3]. I need [1,2,3,4,5].

Comment: @Rahul, Thanks again, you finished before I did. One question why you use `COALESCE` with `left join` there is no null on `t.job_no`

Comment: If you check the fiddle demo, you will see [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: Sorry my bad, that was *M.Alis* query. I have edited your answer again and added the right one. I am outta here now.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into why I got a different result than you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  **Different SQL JOINS**
```

1. > INNER JOIN: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH
   >   tables
2. > LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched
   >   rows from the right table RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right
   >   table, and the matched rows from the left table
3. > FULL JOIN: Return all
   >   rows when there is a match in ONE of the tables

Your Case:
Use `Left Join`

```
 select a.job_no,a.ap_tax_exempt,b.hard_tax_exempt,b.soft_tax_exempt 
            from table_name a left join View_name b on a.job_no=b.job_no
```

[Sql Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)